# HTTP Requests in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, routes

In Laravel we use routes to deal with HTTP requests from the browser.

We can route a request to a controller, do some logic and then return a response.

Now, we can send in variables encapsulated with braces `{}` and the response can be anything, so it seems to me that routing through a controller means that the the properties of the different request methods (POST, GET, PUT etc.) are lost.

For example I could send a POST request with URI `example/{id}` then put in my `routes.php` file

```
Route::post('example/{id}','SomeController@SomeAction');
```

Then I could do something in my controller with the variable `$id` and send a response.

On the other hand I could send a GET request with URI `example/{id}` and alter my route to

```
Route::get('example/{id}','SomeController@SomeAction');
```

The controller would give the same response.

So, am I right in thinking it does not really matter what request method is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts of your question I can identify on a second read-through:

Request methods are not lost. You have access to them with `$request->getMethod()`. So a GET request will return `GET`. You also have the method `isMethod('GET')` available to you, which you could use to get a truthy value which would enable you to return a different kind of response depending on the request type.

With regards to the way you set up your URL, what HTTP verb you use does matter if you're creating a [REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)-ful web service.

I won't explain away what a REST-ful web service is (you can look it up), here is a couple of points from your example:

If you're `get`ting some data, you ought to be doing a `GET` request. It is the verb to represent a read from a resource. If you had to send a lot of data - and your intention is to add data, you ought to `POST` it instead.

The URI should be meaningful in a way that best describes the resource you are manipulating.

Together with the HTTP verb, you can infer the implied action. So if you are `POST`ing to `example/1`, I might infer that (and this is a digression, actually) that you are attempting to *update* record 1 from an example resource. In reality, you would perhaps use the `PUT` verb (which handles update).

Behind the scenes, Laravel uses a POST request due to browser limitations but treats it as a PUT request server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Of course request type does matter. When you want to hide some request data against user and dont show it in url for example: 
`?username="Admin"&nick="admin1"` then u will use POST otherwise you can use GET. When you want get some data u will use GET but when you want to send some data then you should use POST instead.